# I can’t check if `.childNodes[1].childNodes[1]` exists or not

Tags: javascript, html, child-nodes

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.thread')).map((item) => {
    
    if(item.childNodes[1].childNodes[1] === undefined){
        console.log('hey')
    }
})
```

[image]

My point is, if there is no `item.childNodes[1].childNodes[1]` then do something. That’s it.

Comment: [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) accepts a second argument that is the same as calling `.map`, but doesn’t create an intermediate array.

Comment: Sorry i couldnt understand what you tried to say @SebastianSimon

Comment: My English not so well to understand what you say can you edit my code instead?

Comment: Are you aware that `childNodes` includes non-elements, e.g. Text nodes? `.children` contains only elements. If you’re sure about `.childNodes`, use [the optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: If you're targeting a modern browser, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `if (item?.childNodes?.[1]?.childNodes?.[1] === undefined) {`

Comment: [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/416327/10764341) to see if any of the methods work for you ...

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **[optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)** :-

```
if(item?.childNodes?.[1]?.childNodes?.[1] === undefined){
        console.log('hey')
    }
```

Comment: I have a variable that named item on the console by the way.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you there.